# How come people connect their arduinos to buzzers without any coil protection?

Tags: arduino-uno, motor, electronics

If you connect your arduino to a motor you use this schematic:

[image]

However, when it comes to buzzers, which also have a coil, no one protects the circuit:

[image]

What the hell is going on? Are these just buzzers "coiless"? How can I find the type of buzzer I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That kind of "buzzer" doesn't have a coil.  It is a "Piezo Transducer" and uses a crystal to produce the sound.

When you're using a real speaker and producing sound you are doing it very differently to switching a motor or a relay on and off.  You're generating a much smoother waveform and you don't have the sharp "ON-OFF" that causes a collapse of the magnetic field.  You're actually gradually reducing the power and then reversing it to remove the magnetic field then apply a new one in the opposite direction (if you have wired it right of course).

Also the currents involved in driving a speaker like that are minuscule compared to switching a relay, especially when driven direct from the Arduino.  For louder volumes you will use an amplifier, and that deals with the whole protection within itself since it is designed to drive a speaker.

Comment: This picture here states that buzzers have a coil http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-j-B5fWFwJVo/UQTewNIMC7I/AAAAAAAACzA/Y7WLCNIbUGs/s1600/buzzer%20coil.jpg so you are saying that this coil is harmless to arduino?

Comment: That is a specific component within a circuit within a stand-alone buzzer.  It is not a coil directly connected to an Arduino.  It is part of an oscillator circuit that drives the piezo transducer and thus is irrelevant to the Arduino.